# Can there be a difference between explicit operator= call and = operator?

Tags: c++

According to the C++ standard, can there be a difference between `something.operator=(somethingElse)` and `something = somethingElse`?

The first appears in a template with `T& something`, and I'd like to know if it's safe to replace it with the more readable second version.

Comment: Do note that built in types do not have an `operator =`.  If you have `T.operator=(something)` then that `T` cannot be a built in type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tiny differences, because `a = b` does not always invoke an *explicit* operator on object `a`:

- `T a = b;`. It is not an assignment but an initialization: it invokes a copy (or move) construction
- `a = b;` when a is an intrinsic object (integer, pointer, floating point, ...): the `=` operator is a *builtin* one.
- if `T` is trivially copyable, the assignement is allowed even when no `operator =` has been declared on the class, because the compiler use the default builtin assignement operator.

But if an `operator =` method exists and is selected by the overload resolution rules, the assignment operator will invoke it.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't. An explicit `=` operator invokes `operator=()` on a class that declares a suitable `operator=` method, exactly as if the `operator=` method was invoked directly.

This is true for all operators, not just `=`. That's the very definition of what an `operator` class method means: it specifies what gets executed when the corresponding operator is applied to an instance of the class.

Comment: I was about to +1 this, until I read "This is true for all operators not just =". Other operators allow non-members, so that `a @ b` could not anymore be the same as `a.operator @ ...`. One could render a program ill-formed while the other not, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Other than in *copy-initialization contexts*, the short operator expression is equivalent to the functional expression.
[Table 12](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#tab:over.rel.op.func) of the C++ standard draft describes the operator expressions:

Reproduced:

```
Subclause       Expression      As member function         As non-member function

[over.unary]  |     @a    |     (a).operator@ ( )      |    operator@(a)
[over.binary] |     a@b   |     (a).operator@ (b)      |    operator@(a, b)
[over.ass]    |     a=b   |     (a).operator= (b)      |
[over.sub]    |     a[b]  |     (a).operator[](b)      |
[over.ref]    |     a->   |     (a).operator->( )      |
[over.inc]    |     a@    |     (a).operator@ (0)      |    operator@(a, 0)
```

Where `@` is a placeholder for the operator.

---

Of cause, there are other *contextual* use of the `=` operator; in function declarations, such as *defaulted* member functions, *deleted* functions and `= 0; // pure virtual`